# Doubt in applying sigma.please help in applying sigma

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]
I used equation 
$$(AL_1 )^2 + (L_1M_1)^2 +(AL_12 )^2 + (L_2M_2)^2 + (AL_3 )^2 + (L_3M_3)^2 + ......=(a^2 + 1^2 +a^2 + 2^2 +a^2 + 3^2 +a^2 + 4^2 + .......) + ((a-1)^2+1^2 +(a-2)^2+2^2 +(a-3)^2+3^2 +....)$$

So its general term is $$(a)^2 + r^2 + (a-r)^2 + r^2$$

Applying sigma $$\sum_{r=1}^{a-1} (a)^2 + r^2 + (a-r)^2 + r^2$$
I resolved this into $$2(a^2) + 3(r^2) -2ar$$
and applied  sigma$$\sum_{r=1}^{a-1} 2(a^2) + 3(r^2) -2ar$$
I am having problem in applying sigma please anybody help me
please explain in detail since i am still learning about sigma application

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @mzp sir please edit -1 in applying sigma line it is actually (a-1) as upper limit of sigma and also later equations are wrong

Comment: Please follow @Shaun's advice and read the MathJax tutorial, so you can learn how to fix it yourself.

Comment: @mzp please sir change only sigma upper limit to a-1  i tried but it is not formatting  rest i will do

Comment: Just put $a-1$ in curly brackets, i.e. $\{a-1\}$. (I am not allowed to edit just that.)

Comment: I can't tell what exactly you mean by "applying sigma" or what your difficulty is. Is  it the math or the notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sum_\limits{r=1}^{a-1} (2(a^2) + 3(r^2) -2ar)\\
\sum_\limits{r=1}^{a-1} 2a^2 + \sum_\limits{r=1}^{a-1}3r^2 -\sum_\limits{r=1}^{a-1}2ar\\
2a^2(a-1) + 3\frac {(a)(a-1)(2a-1)}{6}-2a\frac {a(a-1)}{2}$

Comment: after solving this sigma 
I got 
1/2(a)(a-1)(4a-
1)
But its answer is 1/2(a-1)(4a-
1)

Comment: I would expect a solution to be cubic, as we have the square of the length of 2(a-1) lines.  So, I am doubtful that the answer could be $\frac 12 (a-1)(4a-1)$

Comment: sir  it was actually printing error in my book.Thanks for answering my question